# Need MySQL query from three tables

Tags: mysql

I have three tables:

```
Items:
Id   |Name   | Price    | Cat_Id 
---- |-------|----------------
 1   | Item1 |   50.00  | 1    
 2   | Item2 |   25.20  | 5

Category:  
Id   |Name  | 
---- |------|
 1   | Cat1 |    
 2   | Cat2 |

Discount:  
Id   |Item_Id| Client_Id|Discount 
---- |-------|----------------
 1   |   1   |   1      | 10    
 2   |   1   |   2      | 15
 3   |   2   |   2      | 6
```

I am trying to get all items with proper discount, which is different for every customer. In this example i have client with Client_Id 1, which have discount for Item1/10/ and he doesn`t have discount on Item2.
The result should look like this:

```
Id   |Name   | Price    | Cat | Discount
---- |-------|----------------|----------
 1   | Item1 |   50.00  | Cat1|   10
 2   | Item2 |   25.20  | Cat5|   0
```

My question is what is the way to build the query. I join first two tables and need to filter the third, but should I use temp table or do query in query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
select di.id,di.Client_Id,it.Name,it.Price,ca.Cat,ifnull(di.Discount,0)
from Discount di
    right join Items it on di.Item_id=it.Id
    left join Category ca on it.Cat_Id=ca.Id
order by di_Id,di.Client_id,It.Name
```

You get all rows from discount and then get all items and look for the category. If an item has no discount(null) you get a 0

Answer (score 3):

It's Simple SQL Query.

```
Select Id, Name, Price, Cat, Discount From Items
left join discount on Items.id=discount.Item_Id 
left join category on Items.cat_id=id
```

Output Like:

```
Id   |Name   | Price    | Cat | Discount
---- |-------|----------------|----------
 1   | Item1 |   50.00  | Cat1|   10
 2   | Item2 |   25.20  | Cat5|   0
```

Comment: Not so simple, I have also Client_Id and the discount is different for all items , Client 1-10 discount, Client 2 - 15 discount on Item1

Comment: hmm. add in where condition to this query.

Comment: You mean query in WHERE clause to filter Client_Id. Is this the best way to solve the problem, cause items table is pretty big?

Answer (score 0):

To get the result you want,

following is the query...

```
select
     i.id item_id,
     d.id discount_id,
     i.name,
     i.price,
     c.name cat_name,
     d.discount
from items i
left join discount d on i.id = d.item_id
left join category c on i.cat_id = c.id
where d.client_id = 1 or d.client_id is null;
/*where condition added after update as OP required*/
```

**UPDATE**

As per OP's comment

```
select
    i.id item_id,d.id discount_id,
    i.name,i.price,c.name cat_name,d.discount
from discount d
left join items i on i.id = d.item_id
left join category c on i.cat_id = c.id
where d.client_id = 2;
```

Comment: I need to filter discount on specific Client e.g. SELECT * FROM Discount WHERE Client_Id = 1 , and then join Items table

Comment: @M.Mihaylov Check for update if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks mate, the point is to show all items and fill discount if it is set in Discount table. If i use WHERE it shows me only items with discount.

Comment: @M.Mihaylov Then you should use first query with `where d.client_id = 1 or d.client_id is null` condition. This will get you the result you want.